# VIM search forward and back re-select searched text

Tags: search, vim, select, mapping, find

I currently am using this to function like in Geany (my old editor) when I select text and press `F3`:

```
vnoremap <silent> * :<C-U>
  \let old_reg=getreg('"')<Bar>let old_regtype=getregtype('"')<CR>
  \gvy/<C-R><C-R>=substitute(
  \escape(@", '/\.*$^~['), '\_s\+', '\\_s\\+', 'g')<CR><CR>
  \gV:call setreg('"', old_reg, old_regtype)<CR>
vnoremap <silent> # :<C-U>
  \let old_reg=getreg('"')<Bar>let old_regtype=getregtype('"')<CR>
  \gvy?<C-R><C-R>=substitute(
  \escape(@", '?\.*$^~['), '\_s\+', '\\_s\\+', 'g')<CR><CR>
  \gV:call setreg('"', old_reg, old_regtype)<CR>
```

Of course this is `*` for search forward for selected text and `#` for backward search of selected text.

What I can't figure out is how to get both of these to re-select the found word (or whatever is selected) once it find's it so I can continue to press `*` or `#` for continued search. So I don't have to re-select what it find's if that's not what I want and want to continue searching.

Comment: Are you looking for `n` and `N` to continue searching forward and backwards?

Comment: No because that command takes me back into insert mode, so what I would need is for it to re-select and take me back to visual again.

Comment: Well `n` and `N` don't move into insert mode, but maybe you're looking for `gv`?

Comment: That's my point, the above posted is a mapping. I have a tried a few times and I can't get that map above to re-select what I have found and stay in visual mode. I'm NOT looking for other keys, VIM is about quick and easy use, so that quick and easy means if I already am using `*` keep using it and just add something to my mapping. `gv` means I have to exit insert back into Visual, then press `gv`, that's a bunch of extra keys for no reason.

Comment: I just spent about 10 min. playing with `gv`, not what I am looking for. `gv` re-selects that LAST used area, I want it to select what I just found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution of adding `v//e<CR>` works, but it has the side effect of making the search to the end, which affects other commands like `n` / `N`. A better option is to re-establish the previous selection at the current position via `1v` (or `1vl` when `'selection'` is `exclusive`).

```
vnoremap <silent> * :<C-U>
\let old_reg=getreg('"')<Bar>let old_regtype=getregtype('"')<CR>
\gvy/<C-R><C-R>=substitute(
\escape(@", '/\.*$^~['), '\_s\+', '\\_s\\+', 'g')<CR><CR>
\gV:call setreg('"', old_reg, old_regtype)<CR>1v
vnoremap <silent> / :<C-U>
\let old_reg=getreg('"')<Bar>let old_regtype=getregtype('"')<CR>
\gvy?<C-R><C-R>=substitute(
\escape(@", '?\.*$^~['), '\_s\+', '\\_s\\+', 'g')<CR><CR>
\gV:call setreg('"', old_reg, old_regtype)<CR>1v
```

Answer (score 0):

GOT IT!!! Found it on another Stackoverflow question kind of related to mine, was hard to find though. Correct usage would be to add this to the end of each query:

```
<Esc>v//e<CR>
```

This takes me back out into normal mode, then visual mode, then repeat last search then select to end. So final code would be:

```
vnoremap <silent> * :<C-U>
  \let old_reg=getreg('"')<Bar>let old_regtype=getregtype('"')<CR>
  \gvy/<C-R><C-R>=substitute(
  \escape(@", '/\.*$^~['), '\_s\+', '\\_s\\+', 'g')<CR><CR>
  \gV:call setreg('"', old_reg, old_regtype)<CR><Esc>v//e<CR>
vnoremap <silent> / :<C-U>
  \let old_reg=getreg('"')<Bar>let old_regtype=getregtype('"')<CR>
  \gvy?<C-R><C-R>=substitute(
  \escape(@", '?\.*$^~['), '\_s\+', '\\_s\\+', 'g')<CR><CR>
  \gV:call setreg('"', old_reg, old_regtype)<CR><Esc>v//e<CR>
```

And that gives the quick fast and easy approach to fast searching of selected region!